# Nativescript contact permission on iOS

Tags: ios, nativescript, contacts, user-permissions, nativescript-plugin

I'm having troubles in order to let my NativeScript app read contacts on iOS. I'm using the library *nativescript-contacts* in order to read all the entries of the address book and the one called *nativescript-permission* in order to ask the user the permission to read contacts.
Unfortunately, the latter seems to work only in Android, where everything works fine: a pop-up appears asking the user to allow the reading of contacts and, if the permission is granted, the contacts are displayed in a list.
In iOS instead, I'm not able to ask for contact permission: no dialog box pops out and when I try to use a function of *nativescript-contacts* (e.g. *getAllContacts()*), the app freezes.

I've tried searching, but the only thing I can do seems to use some native code in order to get these permissions... but I have no idea how.
May you help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things you might need:

1st, did you add in the `Info.plist` file a message for the key `Privacy: Contacts usage description` ? This will display the message you set to the user when prompted the permission alert.

2nd. You can ask for the permission by calling `requestAccess(for:completionHandler:)`. Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontactstore/1402873-requestaccess)

Comment: I added the key in the Info.plist and everything works fine right now.
Many thanks Robert, I was missing a really easy thing!